# Characters being copied are getting multiplied on the text file on c# windows form

Tags: c#, windows, forms, clipboard, multiplication

I am creating a simple clipboard system on C# and every time characters or words are copied, they are getting multiplied on the text file just like on the picture below.
[image]

here is my code

```
        string path = @"C:\\Users\\" + Environment.UserName + "\\Documents\\clipboard.txt";

        if (!File.Exists(path))
        {     
            using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(path)) ;     
            if(File.Exists(path))
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    var text = Clipboard.GetText();
                    File.AppendAllText(path, text);
                    Thread.Sleep(2500);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Well yes, you're appending to the file in an endless loop. What did you *expect* to happen?

Comment: If I'm interpreting this correctly, I think what you want is to check the clipboard for any new content every 2500ms and append that to the end of the text file, but since you've not actually got anything that checks for _new_ content its just going to keep appending the **last** thing you copied over and over again

Comment: yes, and I don't know how should I append the text file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pretty crude fix and I'm sure that there's a much more efficient way to do it than this, but for the time being this should work.

You'll store the last copied text as `lastText` and compare it to the current text in `text`, if they match up then your clipboard hasn't changed, if they don't then you've got new text on your clipboard and should append it to the file.

```
string path = @"C:\\Users\\" + Environment.UserName + "\\Documents\\clipboard.txt";
string lastText = "";

if (!File.Exists(path))
        {     
            using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(path)) ;     
            if(File.Exists(path))
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    var text = Clipboard.GetText();
                    if(lastText != text)
                    {
                        File.AppendAllText(path, text);
                        lastText = text;
                    }              
                    Thread.Sleep(2500);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: It works really well. Thank you, I'll try to add some commands to work all things up.